# Creating variables in Javascript to manipulate the CSS box-shadow

Tags: javascript, html, css, box-shadow

I am creating a CSS editor using Javascript. I would like the User to be able to change the attributes of the CSS box-shadow. I imagine the function would look something like this:

```
var box = document.getElementById("boxDiv");
var h-offset; //= getUserInput (= document.getElementById("textareaID").value;)
var v-offset; //= getUserInput
var blur; //= getUserInput
var spread; //= getUserInput
var color; //= getUserInput

box.style.boxShadow =; //(h-offset,v-offset,blur,spread,color)
```

I am not sure how to format the String in a way the CSS box-shadow can understand it. 
Thanks!

Comment: The syntax for the box-shadow property can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow. Should be a simple matter of concatenating your variables together.

Comment: You can simply use `box.setAttribute("style", "...what you would write in CSS...");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just concatenate the strings together. Keep in mind, that you need to validate the user input first. Otherwise, the `box-shadow` is not properly shown, if the user inserts a wrong value.

```
box.style.boxShadow = offsetX + ' ' + offsetY + ' ' + blurRadius + ' ' + spreadRadius + ' ' + color;
```

With ES6, you can also use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings):

```
box.style.boxShadow = `${offsetX} ${offsetY} ${blurRadius} ${spreadRadius} ${color}`;
```

---

Here is a live example:

```js
function apply() {
   var box = document.getElementById('box');

   var offsetX = document.getElementById('offsetX').value;
   var offsetY = document.getElementById('offsetY').value;
   var blurRadius = document.getElementById('blurRadius').value;
   var spreadRadius = document.getElementById('spreadRadius').value;
   var color = document.getElementById('color').value;
   
   box.style.boxShadow = offsetX + ' ' + offsetY + ' ' + blurRadius + ' ' + spreadRadius + ' ' + color;
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>

<input id="offsetX" placeholder="offsetX" />
<input id="offsetY" placeholder="offsetY" />
<input id="blurRadius" placeholder="blurRadius" />
<input id="spreadRadius" placeholder="spreadRadius" />
<input id="color" placeholder="color" />

<button onclick="apply()">Apply</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I realized that I was not formatting the String correctly.

What I was coding:

```
 box.style.boxShadow = String(h-offset + v-offset + blur + spread + color);
```

What I needed to code:

```
 box.style.boxShadow = String(h-offset + " " + v-offset + " " + blur + " " + spread + " " + color);
```

Almost a 'Well Duh' moment XD

Comment: You shouldn't use a `String()` constructor, you can just leave it away.

Comment: Thanks. I mean either way it works, but I did remove it.

Answer (score -1):

```js
  var first = "10px";
  var second = "20px";
  var third = "red";
  
  $("#bshadow_jquery").css('box-shadow', first + " " + second + " " + third);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#bshadow_css {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px;
}
#bshadow_jquery {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>box-shadow css: 5px 5px #990000:</h2>
<div id="bshadow_css">
<p>this is a block-shadow by css</p>
</div>

<hr style="margin: 50px 0px">

<h2>box-shadow jquery: 5px 5px #990000:</h2>
<div id="bshadow_jquery">
<p>this is a block-shadow by JQuery</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer does not include any explanation and furthermore it does not add any added value compared to the already existing answers (same approach, but unnecessarily adding a jQuery dependency).